# failed to resolve com.stripe:stripe-android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

My project build.gradle like blew, but always error message after sync: failed to resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:+. However, what I think is the stripe is kind of standard in android studio. please enlighten me.....

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  compile project(':CircularImageView')
  compile project(':UrlImageViewHelper')
  compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
  compile project(':DevsmartAndroid')
  compile project(':DenivipVideoComponents_PT3.8')
  compile project(':BluejayDbLibrary')
  compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
  compile project(':AmazonLib')
  compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
  compile files('libs/opentok-android-sdk.jar')
  compile ('com.stripe:stripe-android:+')
}
```

the complete build file,

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':CircularImageView')
    compile project(':UrlImageViewHelper')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':DevsmartAndroid')
    compile project(':DenivipVideoComponents_PT3.8')
    compile project(':BluejayDbLibrary')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':AmazonLib')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/opentok-android-sdk.jar')
    compile ('com.stripe:stripe-android:+')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

```
defaultConfig{
    applicationId "com.bluejayPT.patient"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_DEBUG", "false"
    }
    debug {

        buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_DEBUG", "true"
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest_PT.xml'
        //manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest_SK.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated','src']

        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir('libs')

    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your complete build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution,

add below

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}

into project build.gradle, the problem solved because my project originally migrated from eclipse to android studio, which means the eclipse repositories based on  mavenCentral() not jcenter().